# Issue reshaping an array into (28, 28) for an MNIST image

Tags: python, mnist

When running this code, I want to show the image in matplotlib but am I getting an error in `some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)` where I get the ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (28, 28). Is there any way to fix this issue and get the image in the matplotlib. Thanks for helping me solve the issue.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]


%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_digit = X.loc[[36000]]
print(some_digit)

some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)

plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap=matplotlib.cm.binary, interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to perform reshape on dataframe object. Convert the data frame object to numpy array (some_digit = X.loc[[36000]].to_numpy()). It would fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`some_digit` is a DataFrame, which does not have a `.reshape()` method. You need to get its underlying `numpy` array:

```py
In [3]: some_digit = X.loc[[36000]].to_numpy()

In [4]: type(some_digit)
Out[4]: numpy.ndarray

In [5]: some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
Out[5]:
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
          0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.], ...
```